# Django DRF ModelSerializer isvalid() always false when deserialize JSON

Tags: python, json, django, python-3.x, serialization

Despite all I found here, I don't find any solutions to my problem.

I'm using `django` rest framework to work on REST API in Pycharm on Python 3.x

When I use the `ModelSerializer` in my code, I can create a JSON from my model

```
self.woodrow_attributes = {'name': 'RankA',
                        'gps_position_x': Decimal('40.15'),
                        'gps_position_y': Decimal('45.50'),
                        'gps_position_z': Decimal('30.50')}


self.woodrow = WoodRow.objects.create(**self.woodrow_attributes)



self.woodrow_serializer = WoodRowSerializer(instance=self.woodrow)


data_json = JSONRenderer().render(self.woodrow_serializer.data,)
```

my json is good and contains all information in bytes type :

```
b'{"row_id":1,"name":"RankA","gps_position_x":"40.1500000","gps_position_y":"45.5000000","gps_position_z":"30.5000000"}'
```

And when I want to deserialize it and test if the contents is valid, the answer is always false. I use ModelSerializer and when I run this code :

```
deserialize_data = BytesIO(data_json)
deserialize_data = JSONParser().parse(deserialize_data)
print(deserialize_data)
print(type(deserialize_data))

serializer = WoodRowSerializer(data=deserialize_data)
print(serializer.is_valid())
print(serializer.error_messages)
```

I got this :

```
{'row_id': 1, 'name': 'RankA', 'gps_position_x': '40.1500000', 'gps_position_y': '45.5000000', 'gps_position_z': '30.5000000'}

<class 'dict'>

False

{'required': 'This field is required.', 'null': 'This field may not be null.', 'invalid': 'Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got {datatype}.'}
```

The error said that my data is invalid and datatype but I just print before that it is a `dict`.

When I try my code in python console, it works and the serializer valid my data without error.

Does anyone have the answer for that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`error_messages` attribute of serializer doesn't actually contain error messages that actually occurred when parsing your data. This is static dictionary that just map certain errors to human-readable messages.

The property that you are looking for is called `errors`.

Comment: Thanks ! With errors I got {'name': ['wood row with this name already exists.']} and my error was my name corrupt my unique constraint